# can you suggest an alternative for platform.login

Tags: python, rest, authentication, ringcentral

i recently started experimenting in the RingCentral sandbox environment and facing issues with this part of the code

```
rcsdk = SDK(CLIENTID,CLIENTSECRET,SERVERURL)
platform = rcsdk.platform()
try:
    platform.login(USERNAME,EXTENSION,PASSWORD,JWT)
except Exception as e:
  sys.exit("Unable to authenticate to platform. Check credentials." + str(e))
```

I went to know if there is an alternative to code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code snippet, I can see that the **platform.login()** function signature is incorrect as you are passing extra argument.

Correct function signatures in Python are:

1. Logging with username, password flow: `platform.login(USERNAME, EXTENSION, PASSWORD)`
2. Logging with JWT : `platform.login( jwt=JWT_TOKEN )`

Make sure to replace the UPPERCASE String with the actual credential found in RingCentral Developer Portal for your app's sandbox environment and it should work.

**Reference:**

- https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/authentication

Comment: so just need to use either one of the methods no need to use both ok got it